# How can I detect if I have access to a resource on an FTP server?

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I'm trying to write bash script for file copying from local machine to FTP using `lftp`.

Problem is, when someone enter inaccessible path for `mkdir` or `put`, then `lftp` returns:

```
Access failed: 550 /: Device or resource busy
```

And my Bash script gets stuck and doesn't terminate.

How can I check if I am able to access resource before executing next commands?

Here is the relevant section of my code:

```
OUTPUT=`lftp -u $USER,$PASS -p $PORT $HOST <<HEREDOCUMENT
set ftp:ssl-allow no                                    
mkdir $FTP_DIR                                          
put $LOCAL_DIR/$LOCAL_FILE -o $FTP_DIR/$FTP_FILE        
bye                                                     
HEREDOCUMENT`
```

Comment: Set a timeout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327800/lftp-timeout-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments,
you can prevent the process from getting stuck by using a timeout,
for example:

```
OUTPUT=$(lftp -u $USER,$PASS -p $PORT $HOST <<EOF
set net:timeout 5
set net:max-retries 2
set net:reconnect-interval-base 5
set ftp:ssl-allow no                                    
mkdir $FTP_DIR                                          
put $LOCAL_DIR/$LOCAL_FILE -o $FTP_DIR/$FTP_FILE        
bye                                                     
EOF)
```

[@Marki](https://serverfault.com/users/35054/marki) made an excellent suggestion in a comment:

> larger FTP scripts you may use Perl or similar, which would allow you to perform explicit error handling after each command.

Comment: One may add that for larger FTP scripts you may use Perl or similar, which would allow you to perform explicit error handling after each command.